# Mysql connection refused on digital ocean ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu-18.04

I recently set up lamp on ubuntu 18.04 on digital ocean. Then clone laravel project.

after setting .env and run `php artisan migrate --seed` I got this error

[image]

can't connect to database,

but when I tried to connect using `mysql -u root -p` I could and even create database.

Is this related to some permission or am I missing configuration. my project work fine with the same setup on local and using WSL with ubuntu 18.04

Any suggestion how may I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. I downgraded to 16.04, 18.04 i think has problem with mariadb